# Drupal 7 - add metadata to file on upload

Tags: upload, drupal-7, metadata

I want to let users fill some metadata information i have created while uploading files.

I use file entity and media module and i have created a few fields for the image file type. For instance some of the fields are : Location, category, Title etc.

I can see and complete those fields if i navigate to "admin/content/media". But i would like users to be able to view and fill those fields when they upload their images.

I can't find anything in permissions table for that or any other setting. Can someone give some light?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find something that works. Actually, i downloaded the dev versions of media module ([link](http://drupal.org/project/media)) and file entity module ([link](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity)). The new versions enable users to edit the custom fields when they upload new files.

Hope this information helps someone else too!